# Stokes' Theorem for the upper half space.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

How can I prove Stokes' Theorem $\int_M dω = \int_{∂M} ω$ where $M = \mathbb{H}^ n$, the upper half space.

Comment: [*Stokes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_George_Stokes,_1st_Baronet), not Stoke.

Comment: I'm curious but how did you define the integral in a non-compact area? Is your form compact supported?

Comment: Yes w is compactly supported smooth (n-1) form

Comment: Knight, if you don't find my answer below acceptable (which is fine), would you mind including an answer of your own and accepting it?

Answer (score 2):

In John M. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* there is a proof of Stokes' Theorem (Theorem $14.9$). The proof begins with a proof of Stokes' Theorem for the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}^n$. I recommend checking out the book, it's very good.

Comment: This is an exercise from Bott and Tu, my teacher is taking this book, so thanks!